# App Store Connect Invallid Binary Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, build, binary-files, app-store

Alguien sabe porque me sale esto al tratar de subir la App a la AppStore?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Influye este warning ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Config de Proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Config de info.plist:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco si alguien sabe que puede ser, gracias.

Comment: Si, lo del warning es un causal para que no se pueda subir. Intentaste con 1 en el build?

Comment: @Bicho ya no troll, ya cambie eso, ya no tengo warnings pero tengo el mismo problema, ya lo acabe de intentar y sale lo mismo. Ahora sí ni idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una posible causa es no tener el mismo build y version tanto el proyecto como en los demás targets o Extensiones.

Tener en cuenta que la solución se dio por los mensajes de apple que llegan al correo, en este caso es el siguiente mensaje:

> Your Info.plist contains the UINewsstandIcon sub-property under
> CFBundleIcons, which is intended for use with Newstand features. To
> include Newsstand features, the Info.plist must include the
> UINewsstandApp=true Info.plist key.

Ademas tiene que hacer lo siguiente en el info.plist que se encuentra en esta respuesta que es esencial borrar unos archivos:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977357/xcode-gave-strange-newsstand-error-when-trying-to-submit-an-app
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166434/invalid-image-path-no-image-found-at-the-path-referenced-under-key-cfbundleic

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @Bicho solucionado